# regex pattern for [at] in email address

Tags: c#

I want to extract email " myemail [at] domainemail [dot] com " from html code in string.

So I used this code but it is not working. What should I do ?

```
public static List<string> Fetch_Emails(string Sourcecode)
{
    List<string> Emails = new List<string>();    

    Regex exp = new Regex("\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+(\\[at\\])[A-Z0-9.-]+(\\[dot\\])[A-Z]{2,4}\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
           MatchCollection matchCollection = exp.Matches(Sourcecode);

    foreach (Match m in matchCollection)
    {
        if (!Emails.Contains(m.Value))
        { 
            Emails.Add(m.Value);                        
        }
    }

    return Emails;
}
```

Comment: There is no _simple_ regular expression for this problem. See linked question by LB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern does not support having spaces between the email components and `[at]` or `[dot]`.

To add support for spaces, use `[ ]{0,3}` to allow between 0 and 3 spaces between the components.

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+[ ]{0,3}(\[at\])[ ]{0,3}[A-Z0-9.-]+[ ]{0,3}(\[dot\])[ ]{0,3}[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

Also, instead of escaping the regex, use a C# string literal:

```
Regex exp = new Regex(@"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+[ ]{0,3}(\[at\])[ ]{0,3}[A-Z0-9.-]+[ ]{0,3}(\[dot\])[ ]{0,3}[A-Z]{2,4}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex to process emails. Email RFC defines some quite complicated rules for emails.

Rather use [MailAddres](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Mail.MailAddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and wrap constructor in try catch. Leave heavy lifting of parsing mail addresses to .NET FCL.

If constructor of MailAddress class did not fail, then you have a regular email address and you can extract various email parts.